# determine the http status that will be sent in php

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit

I am trying to write a test case for a class that is managing headers for my application. Among the headers it sends are http status headers. I am using headers_list() to see which headers would be send, were I to send headers now. The problem with headers_list() is that it does not include the http status header (although this seems to be undocumented on php.net). So, I cannot find a way to determine what http status would be sent. Even if I do send the headers (which I'm trying not to do, so I can test a bunch of different things all in one go), the status does not show up in headers_list(). Any ideas?

P.S. I realize I could do this by requesting the page and examining the response, but that makes it very difficult to keep tests at a *unit* level, so I'm trying to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

Either use a [Mock](http://www.phpunit.de/manual/3.0/en/mock-objects.html) that returns the header but doesnt send it or write a Response object, e.g.

```
class HttpResponse 
{
    protected $_status = '200 OK';
    protected $_headers = array();
    protected $_body = null;

    public function setStatus($status)
    {
        $this->_status = $status;
    }

    public function getStatus()
    {
        return $this->_status;
    }

    public function addHeader($name, $value)
    {
        $this->_headers[$name] = $value;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getHeaders()
    {
        return $this->_headers;
    }    

    public function write($data)
    {
        $this->_body .= $data;
        return $this;
    }

    public function send()
    {
        header('HTTP/1.0 ' . $this->_status);
        foreach ($this->headers as $name => $value) {
            header("$name : $value");
        }
        echo $this->_body;
        $this->resetRequest();
    }

   public function resetRequest()
   {
        $this->_status  = '200 OK';
        $this->_headers = array();
        $this->_body    = null;
   }
}
```

So as long as you dont `send()` you can inspect the state through the getters. You could also add a `__toString()` method, that returns the Entire Response as a string and regex it to see if it looks like you expect it to look.